# Creating masking Policy in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create masking policy. Everything looks fine but when I selecting the data from customer table. I am getting the error.
-- Validating policies

```
USE ROLE ANALYST_FULL;
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;
```

SQL compilation error:

> Object 'CUSTOMERS' does not exist or not authorized.

When I switched to ANALYST_FULL role I do not see the same database which I used and table which I created.

Comment: Hi - So the ANALYST_FULL role doesn't have the required permissions on the CUSTOMERS table (or you haven't set the context to the schema where this table exists). This doesn't seem to have anything to do with masking policies

Comment: Please execute: Grant select on <dbname>.<schemaname>.CUSTOMERS to role analyst_FULL;

Comment: If you don't see the database where CUSTOMER is at, your need to grant ANALYST_ROLE usage privilege on the Database and Schema. And then select privilege on the table

Answer (score 0):

check if you have the right privilege for role on the table with:

```
show grants on role ANALYST_FULL;
```

if not then you can grant the role access to select the table with:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE <Database>.<schema>.CUSTOMERS TO ROLE ANALYST_FULL;
```

or all tables in a database. note this is for existing tables and not future tables:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA <Database>.<schema> TO ROLE ANALYST_FULL;
```